# Why isn't handler recognised in test for post request?

Tags: java, spring, testing

My springboot test below tests a controller method that posts data in json form. The problem is that for some reason the test is not recognising the handler (controller) that I am trying to access- It gives me handler: type = null. What is the problem with my code? See below:

Test:

```
@WebMvcTest(QuizController.class)

public class QuizControllerTest {
    @MockBean
    private QuizRepository quizRepository;

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Autowired
    private ObjectMapper objectMapper;

    @Test
    void shouldAddQuestion() throws Exception {
        QuizDTO quizDTO = new QuizDTO(104, "epidemics", 21, 4, "Test Question?", "A", "B", "C", "D", "hint");
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        String json = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(quizDTO);
        mockMvc.perform(post("/adminadd")
                        .with(user("admin").password("password").roles("USER"))
                .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .content(json))
                .andExpect(status().isCreated())
                .andDo(print());
    }
```

Controller class:

```
@PostMapping("/adminadd")
public QuizDTO addQuestion(@RequestBody QuizDTO quizDTO) {

    return quizRepo.addQuestion(quizDTO);
}
```

error message:

```
MockHttpServletRequest:
      HTTP Method = POST
      Request URI = /adminadd
       Parameters = {}
          Headers = [Content-Type:"application/json;charset=UTF-8", Content-Length:"175"]
             Body = {"type":"epidemics","questionIndex":21,"choiceNum":4,"question":"Test Question?","choiceA":"A","choiceB":"B","choiceC":"C","choiceD":"D","correct":null,"hint":"hint","id":104}
    Session Attrs = {org.springframework.security.web.csrf.HttpSessionCsrfTokenRepository.CSRF_TOKEN=org.springframework.security.web.csrf.DefaultCsrfToken@5bde6148, SPRING_SECURITY_CONTEXT=SecurityContextImpl [Authentication=UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken [Principal=org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User [Username=admin, Password=[PROTECTED], Enabled=true, AccountNonExpired=true, credentialsNonExpired=true, AccountNonLocked=true, Granted Authorities=[ROLE_USER]], Credentials=[PROTECTED], Authenticated=true, Details=null, Granted Authorities=[ROLE_USER]]]}

Handler:
             Type = null
```

```
MockHttpServletResponse:
           Status = 403
    Error message = Forbidden
          Headers = [X-Content-Type-Options:"nosniff", X-XSS-Protection:"1; mode=block", Cache-Control:"no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate", Pragma:"no-cache", Expires:"0", X-Frame-Options:"DENY"]
     Content type = null
             Body = 
    Forwarded URL = null
   Redirected URL = null
          Cookies = []
```

The main issue I am trying to solve is why is handler: type = null? What is the solution?

Comment: What makes you think your handler isn't found. You get a 403 (security related) not a 404 (not found).

Comment: I understand now. I didn't understand the meaning of 403. That makes sense because the controller I'm accessing requires admin rights. Thank you for your help